# Convert spreadsheet column index into character sequence

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet

How can I the get character sequence, for example `"AA"` from column index `26`?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a recursive hash that will handle indexing for you:

```
index_hash = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key] = hash[key - 1].next }.merge({0 => "A"})
index_hash[26] #=> "AA"
```

The key here is the `.next` method, which when sent to a string, will return the alphabetically following string, e.g. `"CD".next #=> "CE"`.

Could you clarify your first question?

Answer (score 4):

```
class Numeric
  Alph = ("A".."Z").to_a
  def alph
    s, q = "", self
    (q, r = (q - 1).divmod(26)) && s.prepend(Alph[r]) until q.zero?
    s
  end
end

(26+1).alph #=> "AA"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c = "A"
26.times { c = c.next }
c # => "AA"
```