# Generate letters to represent number using ruby?

Tags: ruby, math, numerical

I would like to generate a sequence of letters i.e. "A", "DE" "GJE", etc. that correspond to a number. The first 26 are pretty easy so 3 returns "C", 26 returns "Z", and 27 would return "AA", 28 "AB", and so on.

The thing I can't quite figure out is how to do this so it will handle any number passed in. So if I pass in 4123 I should get back some combination of 3 letters since (26 * 26 * 26) allows for up to +17,000 combinations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This basically is a base-26 number (but without digits in the base)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - This problem is more complex, it turns out. I think the key characteristic that leads to trouble is that `A` means "0" in some cases (as the "ones" digit) but `A` means "1" in other cases (as the "tens/twenty-sixes" digit. Funny to think though that someone at Microsoft had to solve this ;)

Comment: I'm missing something. Why is "A" special? A=1*1=1, AA=1*26+1*1=27.

Comment: @glennmcdonald "A" is not special. "A" always corresponds to "1". What is special is that "0" is skipped. Imagine in decimal, counting up, skipping "0": 1, 2, ..., 8,  9, 11, 12, ..., 18, 19, 21, 22, ..., 98, 99, 111, 112, ... Now, if you do that in heptabidecimal (base 27) instead of decimal, you get the sequence.

Comment: Oh, duh, right. Probably easier to do it in base 26 for real, with A as 0. Not clear in the question whether the zeroless thing is a requirement or an artifact of the imagined solution.

Comment: @glennmcdonald That won't work. If you consider "A" as "0", then you would have to consider there are arbitrary length of preceding "A"s in front of any sequence (i.e., "B" = "AB" = "AAB" = ...) just like ("1" = "01" = "001" = ...), but that is not what you want, so your idea does not work.

Comment: Right, I understand. Up to Ryan whether that's OK or not. If the task is just to turn numbers into letter-sequences, then it's fine to ignore leading As just like it's fine to strip leading 0s in decimal. It wasn't clear to me whether it was a requirement for A to be 1 and AA to be 27, etc., or whether that was just an obvious starting point.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about that. I was looking for 1 to be A and 27 to be AA, yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578555

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class Numeric
  Alph = ("a".."z").to_a
  def alph
    s, q = "", self
    (q, r = (q - 1).divmod(26)); s.prepend(Alph[r]) until q.zero?
    s
  end
end

3.alph
# => "c"
26.alph
# => "z"
27.alph
# => "aa"
4123.alph
# => "fbo"
```

Comment: I believe this is the only correct solution so far, though I'm not exactly sure what's going on...

Comment: Totally awesome. I also took away a new piece of insight from this. The way to calculate the total combinations is something like !(26 ^ (n-1)). I'm not a mathematician so this might be completely made up but this would give you (26 ^ 3) + (26 ^ 2) + (26 ^ 1) for three letters, and (26 ^ 2) + (26 ^ 1) for two, etc.

Comment: What is the best way to use this in a rails application? To include the class in the lib directory and require it?

Comment: @JeremyRichards Place it in your `config/initializers/numeric.rb` file

Answer (score 17):

A tweak on @sawa original answer for Ruby 2.0 since I couldn't get his to work as is:

```
class Numeric
  Alpha26 = ("a".."z").to_a
  def to_s26
    return "" if self < 1
    s, q = "", self
    loop do
      q, r = (q - 1).divmod(26)
      s.prepend(Alpha26[r]) 
      break if q.zero?
    end
    s
  end
end
```

and here it is going in reverse from string to integer:

```
class String
  Alpha26 = ("a".."z").to_a

  def to_i26
    result = 0
    downcased = downcase
    (1..length).each do |i|
      char = downcased[-i]
      result += 26**(i-1) * (Alpha26.index(char) + 1)
    end
    result
  end

end
```

Usage:

```
1234567890.to_s26 
# => "cywoqvj"

"cywoqvj".to_i26  
# => 1234567890

1234567890.to_s26.to_i26
# => 1234567890

"".to_i26
# => 0

0.to_s26
# => ""
```

Comment: That's a good catch. I've updated my answer so that anything less than 1 will return an empty string.

Comment: take note the String#to_i26 method modifies the string it's called on downcasing it. To change that, change `downcase!` to `string = downcase` and `char = self[-i]` to `char = string[-i]`

Answer (score 8):

Strings do have a `succ` method so they are usable in a Range. The successor to "Z" happens to be "AA", so this works:

```
h = {}
('A'..'ZZZ').each_with_index{|w, i| h[i+1] = w } 
p h[27] #=> "AA"
```

Comment: Using this method, you cannot just randomly calculate the string for a certain number on the spot, but you have to go through all the numbers up to the target number.

Comment: Sawa's answer is much better for performance reasons, but if you're going with this response as a quick and dirty method, the following will do it in one line:  x = 27; ('A'..'ZZZ').reduce(0) {|i, l| break(l) if (i+1) == x; i+1 }

Comment: Actually this is faster than @Sawa (17 times according to fruity), provided the hash is re-used. It does so on the cost of using much more memory.

Comment: This answer is generating the hash in advance for a fixed range, and is merely referring to it when you need it. My answer generates it for an arbitrary sequence on the spot. They cannot be compared.

Answer (score 4):

I liked this answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17785576/514483

```
number.to_s(26).tr("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopq", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work. The question states that 27 should return "AA" and this method returns "BB"

Comment: Sorry - this answer worked for my case where I didn't care about the exact letters generated, but I agree it's wrong.

Comment: I ended up using this, as I needed a zero

Answer (score 2):

Using the base conversion method found [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/base-conversion-method.html). I also changed it for the lack of "0" that we have in this numbering system. End cases have been addressed.

```
def baseAZ(num)
  # temp variable for converting base
  temp = num

  # the base 26 (az) number
  az = ''

  while temp > 0

    # get the remainder and convert to a letter
    num26 = temp % 26
    temp /= 26

    # offset for lack of "0"
    temp -= 1 if num26 == 0

    az = (num26).to_s(26).tr('0-9a-p', 'ZA-Y') + az
  end

  return az
end
```

irb I/O:

```
>> baseAZ(1)
=> "A"
>> baseAZ(26^2 + 1)
=> "Y"
>> baseAZ(26*26 + 1)
=> "ZA"
>> baseAZ(26*26*26 + 1)
=> "YZA"
>> baseAZ(26*26*26 + 26*26 + 1)
=> "ZZA"
```

Comment: Insightful to notice that this number system "lacks a zero", though now obvious in hindsight. I discovered that OP is looking to convert to [a "Bijective Base-26" system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal#Bijective_base_26), and searching by that keyword there appears to be no transliteration-based algorithm for the conversion. I think a simple transliteration-based algorithm is impossible because there will always be a certain single-digit symbol in the no-zeroes system that must map to a two-digit symbol in the zeroes system.

Answer (score 2):

```
def letter_sequence(n)
    n.to_s(26).each_char.map {|i| ('A'..'Z').to_a[i.to_i(26)]}.join
end
```

Comment: Nice slick solution.

Comment: This doesn't quite work according to the question. For example, 27 should return "AA" and this returns "BB"

Comment: This definitely is wrong. 701 should return ZY and not BAY

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is a short performant recursion based solution

```rb
class Numeric
  # 'z' is placed in the begining of the array because 26 % 26 is 0 not 26
  Alph = ['z'] + ("a".."y").to_a

  def to_alph

    # if self is 0 or negative return a blank string.
    # this is also used to end the recursive chain of to_alph calls
    # so don't replace this with raising an error or returning anything else

    return '' if self < 1

    # (otherwise) return two concatenated strings:
    # the right side is the letter for self modules 26
    # the left side is comprised of:
    #  1. minus one, because this is not a zero-based numbering system.
    #     therefore, round numbers (26, 52...) should return one digit 'z'
    #     instead of two digits 'aa' or 'ba'.
    #  2. divide by 26 and call to_alph on that.
    #     this repeats recursively for every digit of the final string,
    #     plus once more that will return '' to end the recursion chain.

    return ((self - 1) / 26).to_alph + Alph[self % 26]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`('a'..'zzz').to_a[n-1]` would cover for the first 18_278.

Answer (score 0):

Based on sawa's answer, I wanted a method that worked independently, albeit recursively, to achieve the desired outcome:

```
def num_to_col(num)
  raise("invalid value #{num} for num") unless num > 0
  result, remainder = num.divmod(26)
  if remainder == 0
    result -= 1
    remainder = 26
  end
  final_letter = ('a'..'z').to_a[remainder-1]
  result > 0 ? previous_letters = num_to_col(result) : previous_letters = ''
  "#{previous_letters}#{final_letter}".upcase
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the numerical position of a character in the alphabet by subtracting 96 from its ordinal, like so:

```
"a".ord - 96
=> 1

"z".ord - 96
=> 26
```

You can also fetch the alphabetical character by its numerical position by adding 96, like so:

```
(1 + 96).chr
=> "a"

(26 + 96).chr
=> "z"
```