# printing a list of chronological strings in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to print chronological strings in ruby? like the headers of excel `A - Z`, then `AA, AB, AC`. is this possible in ruby? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate letters to represent number using ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632304/generate-letters-to-represent-number-using-ruby)

Comment: @sawa: The posts, while related in substance, are actually two different questions. This post simply wishes to list strings, while the other wishes to utilize math for the finding of similar type strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is. try

```
string = 'A'
99.times { puts string.succ! }
```

Comment: the question was is it possible. he's not asking for a complete solution.  and if you want it to start at 'A', then just put it in a while loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Numeric
  Alph = ("A".."Z").to_a
  def alph
    s, q = "", self
    (q, r = (q - 1).divmod(26)) && s.prepend(Alph[r]) until q.zero?
    s
  end
end

[1, 2, 3].map(&:alph) # => ["A", "B", "C"]
[26, 27, 28].map(&:alph) # => ["Z", "AA", "AB"]
```