# Transform Integer Cell Range into Excel Cell Range

Tags: arrays, ruby, excel, cells

I am coding in Ruby / Rails, and I have a cell range, an example is:

```
[0,1]..[0,3] with the convention [row, column]..[row..column]
```

Excel uses cell ranges like:

```
A2:A4 with the convention <column><row>:<column><row>
```

I need to convert from the former to the latter.
It is mainly the letter's that I am concerned with:

```
A => 0,
B => 1,
C => 2,
AA => 26
AB => 27
```

How would I go about doing that?

I essentially need to do the reverse of this:

[Generate letters to represent number using ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632304/generate-letters-to-represent-number-using-ruby)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in Excel or Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

### VBA Solution

```
Sub test_JohnLinux()

MsgBox ColLet(4) & vbCrLf & InvColLet("D")

End Sub
```

Get number from letters :

```
Public Function InvColLet(x As String) As Long
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x).EntireColumn.Column
End Function
```

Get letters from numbers :

```
Public Function ColLet(x As Integer) As String
With ActiveSheet.Columns(x)
    ColLet = Left(.Address(False, False), InStr(.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Apologies, I don't think I was clear enough that I am looking for a Ruby solution.

Comment: No problem, I had this already done as I use it pretty often in Excel! If it is ok with you, I'll let the answer here!

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby Solution**

Credit must go to Howard, I adapted the answer from here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/generate-excel-column-name-from-index

```
excel_column_ref =-> array_column_ref do
  ref = "A"
  array_column_ref.times{ ref.next! }
  ref
end
```

This returns a proc.

Usage `excel_column_ref[26] = 'AA'`